# Access Activity Method From AsyncTask Callback Interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask

I have several activities and one asyncTask that uses the same interface for callback methods as below

### The interface used by all

```
public interface AsyncTaskCallback {
    void onCookie(CookieManager cookieManager);
    void onResponse(String response);
    void onProgress(String... values);
    void onError(Exception e);
}
```

### AsyncTask1 is called from all activities as follows

```
public void exec_taskt() {
   alertDialog.SetText("Sending Request...");
   AsyncTask1 task1 = new AsyncTask1("https://stackoverflow.com");
   task1.setCookieManager(cookiejar);
   task1.setCallback(this);
   task1.execute();
}
```

### Each Activity also implements the interface

```
@Override
public void onCookie(CookieManager cookieManager) {
    cookiejar = cookieManager;
}

@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        PostProc(response);
    }catch (Exception e){ // ERROR HERE
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onProgress(String... values) {
    alertDialog.SetText(values[0]);
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    ///SAME ERROR HERE TOO
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

private void PostProc(String response) {
    //the response string is parsed and displayed in a recyclerview in this method
    //this method is slightly different for each activity
}
```

### AsyncTask1

```
public class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   private String address = "";
   private CookieManager mCookieManager;
   private Exception mException;
   private AsyncTaskCallback mCallback;


   public AsyncTask1 (String page) {
        this.address = page;

   }

   public void setCookieManager(CookieManager cm) {
    this.mCookieManager = cm;
   }

   public void setCallback(AsyncTaskCallback cb) {
     this.mCallback = (AsyncTaskCallback) cb;

   }

   @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
  try{
        //all code here is executed without error 
        //code skipped for simplicity 
        // basically just loads the given url and then...
        publishProgress("Page Loaded");
        mCallback.onCookie(mCookieManager);
        mCallback.onResponse(response);

        return response;
  } catch (Exception e) {
        publishProgress("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        mCallback.onError(e);
        return "";
    }

 @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    Log.d(tag, TextUtils.join(",", values));
    mCallback.onProgress(values);
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

The errors I get are marked

> ERROR HERE

in the code above. and the message is as follows

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

My main suspect is the `PostProc()` method in the activity that does play with the UI component. But doesnt implementing the interface in the activity mean that part of the code runs in the main UI thread? I know you can pass the activity instance to the asyncTask and call the `PostProc()` method from postexecute of the asyncTask but I would like to explore an alternative way to it, since the same asynctask is accessed by other activities as well. the returns are the same for all activities. Only the `PostProc` Method is different.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *But doesnt implementing the interface in the activity mean that part of the code runs in the main UI thread?* **no** obvious choice is either use onPostExecute or post execution to UI thread

Comment: I suggest to migrate to RxJava or @Santanu Sur answer. AsyncTask will be deprecated soon

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `callback interface` you can use a `android.os.Handler()` which is associated with the `Looper.getMainLooper()` to update the views like:-

```
AsyncTask1 task1 = new AsyncTask1(android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(),  msg -> { 
 // handle message sent from asyncTask
  return false;
}), url);
```

Then in `task1` send the message using using the handler

```
public AsyncTask1 (Handler handler, String page) {
    this.address = page;
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

then ,

```
Message message = new Message();
message.obj = uiData;
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

The handler `onHandleMessage` will always execute on the `main looper` !